# IE7 awkward list spacing

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

I have a large menu built from lists.

It is displaying correctly in all the modern browsers I have tried and IE8, however in IE7 the list items appear to be given large amounts of margin of varying size depending on the size of the list item *(see image comparison below)*:

[image: Comparison between a good browser and IE7]

Unfortunately the debugging tools in IE7 are less than optimal and I am having a real hard time working out where the issue is coming from. The source code is a bit lengthy to post here so I have made a JSfiddle for your viewing pleasure.

[View source code and working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hKhMu/5)

Can anyone see where this mystery spacing is coming from, and how can I put it straight?

Comment: @Mark yes, not in the fiddle but in the live version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IE7 the `<ul>` tags are inheriting a `line-height : 1.5em`, disabling it in ie7 removes the annoying spacing. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hKhMu/6/)

This condition is the culprit

```
ul {
    /* line-height: 1.5em; */
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

**Additional**

Ok I see what you mean about the white gap. This looks like its (surprise surprise) one of those annoying ie7 'features'. I just got round it by using a hack

```
ul li, ul li a {
    /* Needed in ie7 to stop list items expanding vertically
    *line-height:1.2em;
}
```

with

```
* html ul li a {
    height:15px;
}
```

or

```
ul#map > li > a.map-item {
    height:auto;
    *height:15px;
}
```

[Fiddle with no spacing in IE7](http://jsfiddle.net/hKhMu/9/)

A better way would be to create an IE7 only stylesheet and declare this as standard rather than relying on a hack.

Comment: Thanks that fixes some of the spacing issues. Their is still spacing issues with a list item below an open submenu and between top level list items having large spacing above them.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the second problem. See the list item after an open `ul.child` ("Barriers to communication" in your JSfiddle), and see the large gap between "Barriers to communication" and "Health Safety and Security"

Comment: You're right, I did misunderstand the second part. See more info in answer, don't think I can be of much more help than that.

Comment: Thanks David I apply IE specific classes to the `<html>` element so I can target specific versions of IE like so `.ie7 .otherClass`. That works I also found `overflow:hidden` works. There is still the issue of space on "Barriers to communication" (The first element after a ul.child element) and think this has to do with floats, but I'll mark this as solved because you've been a great help. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding CSS to reset all the styles to the same for all browsers?

By including a reset CSS file such as: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ may help with your issue.

Comment: I do use a reset in the live version. Just not in the fiddle (long enough as it is)